# Databinding in ASP.NET and autoselecting 2 checklists based equal ID

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a drop down list and 2 check box lists. When I select a store from the drop down the 2 check box lists should automatically check the names of the customers and employees associated with that store. The foreign key for the customers and employees table is store_id.

```
protected void ddlstore_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int storeId = int.Parse(ddlstore.SelectedValue);

    using (StuffContainer context = new StuffContainer())
    {
        List<Employee> employees = context.Employees.ToList();

        foreach(Employee item in employees)
        {

        }
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        using (StuffContainer context = new StuffContainer())
        {
            ddlstore.DataSource = context.Stores.ToList();
            ddlstore.DataTextField = "Name";
            ddlstore.DataValueField = "Id";
            ddlstore.DataBind();

            chkemp.DataSource = context.Customers.ToList();
            chkemp.DataTextField = "FName";
            chkemp.DataValueField = "Id";
            chkemp.DataBind();

            chkcust.DataSource = context.Employees.ToList();
            chkemp.DataTextField = "FName";
            chkemp.DataValueField = "Id";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related, but the last two lines should be `chkcust`, instead of `chkemp`.

Comment: you should reformat this into legible code and add a question regarding something that is specifically not working including what you have tried already.

Answer (score 0):

```
int storeId = int.Parse(ddlstore.SelectedValue);
using (StuffContainer context = new StuffContainer())
{
List<Employee> employees = context.Employees.ToList();
foreach(Employee item in employees)
{
if(item.store_id == storeId )
{
chkemp.Items.FindByText(item.FName).Selected = true;    
}
}
}
```

Comment: I actually got an error on this line: chkemp.Items.FindByText(item.FName).Selected = true;